# Multiplicative Persistence program in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I can't get my program to work. The problem is a kata from Codewars:
*Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.*
    Example:

```
persistence(39) === 3 // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
                   // and 4 has only one digit

persistence(999) === 4 // because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
                    // 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2

persistence(4) === 0 // because 4 is already a one-digit number
```

I've gone through answers to similar problems here already. This is my code:

```
var count = 0;
var product = 1;

function persistence(num) {
  if (num.toString().length == 1) {
    count+=0;
    return count;
  }
  for (i of num.toString()) {
    product *= Number(i);
  }
  count++;
  var newProduct = product;

  // reset product to 1 so that line ten does not
  // start with the product from the last loop
  product = 1;
  persistence(newProduct);
}
```

I can't tell what the problem is. Initially I was getting a maximum call stack exceeded error. I researched that and realized I did this for my base case:

```
if (num.length == 1) {
  count+=0;
  return count;
}
```

instead of

```
if (num.toString().length == 1) {
  count+=0;
  return count;
}
```

My logic seems sound. What could the problem be?

Comment: Your `persistence` function doesn't actually have a return statement, so it returns undefined.

Comment: You should never, EVER run a function inside the function. It's really bad practice. I'm working on a nice little jsfiddle for you, wait for a little while and I should have it finished for ya...

Comment: @user184994 This part of the code is supposed to be where a value gets returned:

if (num.toString().length == 1) {
    count+=0;
    return count;
  }

Comment: @SimonHyll what about recursion? With the correct branches it would work

Comment: @Wryhder, Sorry, I mean where you're using recursion, so you also need to return `persistence(newProduct);`

Comment: @Li357 "work" and "good practice" are two completely separate concepts. Kinda like it works to fix anything with duct tape, but you should really consider nails when building a house.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I added the return keyword, but now something weird is happening. On every new call to the persistence function, count++ adds to the last value stored at last call, the same kind of problem I tried to avoid with the product variable. I would reset it as well, but where would be a good position for the statement? Inside the if statement containing the base case seems right, but then the the returned value would now be wrong.

Comment: This is what I mean:
console.log(persistence(999));  => 4
console.log(persistence(39));    => 7
console.log(persistence(4));      => 7
console.log(persistence(999));  => 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a much better way of solving your problem, complete with comments that I think gives a pretty clear explanation of what's going on.

```
function persistence(num) {    
    // Create a new function that you'll use inside your main function
    function multiply(n) {
        // Multiply the first number by next number in the array
        // until the entire array has been iterated over
        return n.reduce(function(a,b){return a*b;});
    }
    // Set the count to 0
    var count =0;     

    // Use a while loop to iterate the same number of times
    // as there are digits in num
    while (num.toString().length > 1) {
        // Splits the num into an array
        num= num.toString().split("");
        // Runs multiply on our num array and sets num to the returned
        // value in preparation of the next loop.
        // The multiply function will  for 39 run 3 * 9 = 27,
        // next iteration we've set num to 27 so multiply will be
        // 2 * 7 = 14, then 1 * 4 = 4, and since num 4 now
        // has a length <= 1 the loop stops.
        num = multiply(num);
        // Increase count by 1 each iteration, then run the next 
        // iteration in the loop with the new value for num being
        // set to the result of the first multiplication.
        count++;
    }

    return count; // return the value of count
}

console.log(persistence(39));// === 3 // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
                   // and 4 has only one digit

console.log(persistence(999));// === 4 // because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
                    // 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2

console.log(persistence(4));// === 0 // because 4 is already a one-digit number
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8xmpnzng/

Answer (score 1):

Use "of" instead of "in". "in" looks for properties. "of" increments an array.

```
var count = 0;
var product = 1;

function persistence(num) {
  if (num.toString().length == 1) {
    count+=0;
    return count;
  }
  for (i of num.toString()) {
    product *= Number(i);
  }
  count++;
  var newProduct = product;

  // reset product to 1 so that line ten does not
  // start with the product from the last loop
  product = 1;
  persistence(newProduct);
}
```

Comment: I've made the change. Thanks

Comment: `Number.toString` returns a `String` not an `Array`. In Javascript it isn't possible to iterate trough a string.

Comment: * You can however use string.split("") to turn a string into an array

Comment: @SimonHyll, to be pedantic here I would say that `str.split('')` returns a new array from the string value `str`, it does not *turn* `str` into an array ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's this block:

```
for (i in num.toString()) {
  product *= Number(i);
}
```

That's a for...in loop, which is used to iterate over keys in an object.  If you want to multiply each digit of the `num` string together, you could split the string into an array, and use the reduce method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
//this coerces the number into a string
const numString = num + '' 
//this is the function to pass as the first argument into the reduce method
const multiplyAll = (accumulator, currentVal) => accumulator * Number(currentVal)
let product = numString.split('').reduce(multiplyAll, 1)
```

It's generally best practice to avoid declaring global variables outside of a function's scope, but you can do a cool trick with your recursion where you declare your count as a parameter in your function like so:

```
function persistence(num, count = 0) {
```

And then when you call it again with recursion, you simply add 1 like so:

```
function persistence(product, count + 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simpler way of Persistence:**

```
let countIteration = 1;
function persistence(num) {
  let numStr = num.toString();
  if(numStr.toString().length === 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  let numArr = numStr.split("");
  let persistRes = numArr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc = curr * acc);
  if (persistRes.toString().length !== 1) {
    countIteration += 1;
    return persistence(persistRes);
  }
  else {
    return countIteration;  
  }
} 


console.log(persistence(39)); // === 3
console.log(persistence(15)); // === 1
console.log(persistence(999));// === 4
```